# How do I show the Dock in full-screen mode?

Tags: macos, dock

This one took me awhile to discover, but you can show the Dock while in Lion's new full-screen mode:

Place your cursor to the side where you currently store your Dock (right, left, or bottom), so that it's sitting on the last pixel of that edge. Then *lift your finger* and *push* towards the edge again, holding it in the push. Voilà, the Dock appears.

Small thing, but I found this particular interface just brilliant. It prevents the Dock showing up accidentally, which could be a common problem in full-screen mode, given that, well, we're using the entire screen all the way up to that edge that normally triggers the Dock.

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question, but you should ask as if you don't know the answer and then post the answer as an answer (*phew*). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The answer you posted in the question (unorthodox, yes) is correct: you have to move the mouse toward the edge of the screen in a separate motion.

But also, note that you don't *have* to lift your finger. You can just move the mouse to the edge of the screen, pause, and give it a little extra nudge.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't reliably work for me after all.

Comment: I've found [a method](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/112514/4395) that works for me every time.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the Dock to appear for full-screen app, *rest* (don't click) your finger on the mouse anywhere on the screen, while swiping to the bottom of the screen. The Dock will then appear immediately when you hit bottom.

---

Note that none of the other methods described here work reliably for me, but this one does every time.